# How to ensure that a glob command 'finds' the files I need to aggregate?

Tags: python, path, glob

I'm trying to train a new Tensorflow model, and need to aggregate .xml files into a single .csv.  I found a script to do so, but it uses the glob module - something I'm not familiar with.

I'm looking for help in understanding how this code works so I can tweak it appropriately.

I am executing the .py from a directory that contains two sub-directories with .jpg and .xml files.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
xml_list = []
for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for member in root.findall('object'):
        value = (root.find('filename').text,
                 int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                 int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                 member[0].text,
                 int(member[4][0].text),
                 int(member[4][1].text),
                 int(member[4][2].text),
                 int(member[4][3].text)
                 )
        xml_list.append(value)
column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
return xml_df


def main():
    image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'annotations')
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
    xml_df.to_csv('raccoon_labels.csv', index=None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

No issues with running the code - it creates the .csv file, but as there is no data under the headers, I assume that it's not finding any .xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Your `glob` call is badly written. You need to ask it to go inside subfolders

```py
glob.glob(path + '**/*.xml')
```

Comment: Makes sense - without the ** it's just looking for .xml in that one directory.  Problem is that even when I move the .py script to the sub-directory with the .xml files it still doesn't see them...and I tried the ** to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!  The 'annotations' folder needed to be re-directed, and that solved it.

Also, found an even better version of this script: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/xml_to_csv.py